# Is this Chrome and Safari's bug

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, events, safari, onfocus

I have very simple code as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title><style>span {display:none;}  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <p><input type="text" id="a"/> <span>focus fire</span></p>

<p><input type="password" /> <span>focus fire</span></p>


  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


<script>

    $("input").focus(function () {

        $(this).next("span").css('display', 'inline').fadeOut(1000);
        alert("he");
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#a").focus();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome and Safari, alert keeps firing, comparing to IE, FF, Opera, they only fire once. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Chrome and Safari focus back on the element again after the alert is dismissed, which causes another alert to fire, and so on. The other browsers just don't focus on anything after the alert is dismissed, which is why it doesn't fire endlessly.